# Adding dashes at certain positions in a string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

I've created a function to add dashes (-) at a certain position for each given string.

```
const addDashes = (string) => {
   let splittedString;
   splittedString = string.split('');
   splittedString.splice(3, 0, "-")
   splittedString.splice(10, 0, "-")
   return splittedString.join("");
}
```

Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/src87u6e/

So the thing is that a dash should be added after the first 3 letters, and then another one after the other first 6 digits.

I was wondering if there is a better/cleaner solution than this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use regular expressions:

```js
const addDashes = str => str.replace(/^(.{3})(.{6})/, '$1-$2-')
console.log(addDashes('0123456789abcd'))
```

The pattern `^(.{3})(.{6})` captures 3 and then 6 chars at the start of the string (`^`) and then replaces the whole thing (that is, 9 chars) with the first capture (`$1`), dash, the second one, dash.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

A more general solution is cleaner to achieve with arrays:

```js
// insert a character at given positions of the string
const insertAt = (str, what, where) => [...str]
    .map((c, n) => where.includes(n) ? what + c : c)
    .join('');

console.log(insertAt('0123456789abcd', '-', [3, 9]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const addDashes = (string) => string.slice(0, 3) + "-" + string.slice(3, 9) + "-" + string.slice(9);

console.log(addDashes("ABC0000000000001"))
```

Comment: even better ;))